# como obtener ultimo resultado de un group by

Tags: mysql

Duda existencial :D
Tengo este query que me trae un un valor acumulado; pero solo necesito el ultimo valor de cada grupo pero el group by siempre toma el primer valor :( . Alguna sugerencia?

```
//// QUERY 
SELECT t.id,YEAR(fecha),MONTH(fecha),
@running_total:=@running_total + total_efectivo+ total_facturado AS acumulado
FROM 
( SELECT id_hist as id, date(fecha) as fecha, sum(tipo_pago) as total_facturado ,sum(total) as total_efectivo 
FROM `historico` 
GROUP BY fecha)t JOIN (SELECT @running_total:=0) r
```

| id | año | mes | acumulado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 | 5 | 1110 |
| 12 | 2019 | 5 | 1830 |
| 21 | 2019 | 5 | 3020 |
| 32 | 2019 | 5 | 3580 |
| 38 | 2019 | 5 | 4385 |
| 48 | 2019 | 5 | 5345 |
| 60 | 2019 | 5 | 6650 |
| 72 | 2019 | 5 | 7440 |
| 81 | 2019 | 6 | 7830 |
| 84 | 2019 | 6 | 7970 |

Al agrupar el resultado es: agrego el GROUP BY MONTH(fecha)

| id | año | mes | acumulado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 | 5 | 1110 |
| 81 | 2019 | 6 | 7830 |

Lo esperado o deseado es:

| id | año | mes | acumulado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 72 | 2019 | 5 | 7440 |
| 84 | 2019 | 6 | 7970 |

De antemano muchas gracias a quien me pueda explicar qué puedo hacer, aportaría enormemente a mi aprendizaje.

Answer (score 0):

Estás teniendo el típico problema del `GROUP BY` en MYSQL. Y digo en MySQL porque hay otros sistemas gestores que te impiden proyectar un campo por el que no agrupas sin totalizar. Supongo que tarde o temprano terminará por imponerse esta restricción para evitar estos descuidos.

No es que te enseñe el primer registro, sino que podría enseñarte cualquiera. Lo que no puedes hacer es pedir que te muestre un campo de los que cambian en ese grupo. Puedes pedirle el `MAX()`, el `MIN()`, e incluso el `GROUP_CONCAT()` para que te los muestre todos, pero no uno sin más, porque el sistema gestor no sabe cuál darte y te da cualquiera, habitualmente el primero que se encuentra.

En tu caso, como necesitas el último `id` de cada grupo, entiendo que un `MAX(id_hist) id` resolvería tu problema, porque supongo que irás registrando y asignando los autonuméricos en orden.

Espero haber respondido a tu pregunta. Si necesitas más detalles, déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Ya intenté con el MAX(id_hist) y me trae el MAX de la tabla original  y no del resultset (no se si me hago entender)... en la tabla original, el id max corresponde al ultimo registro de ese mes y no al ultimo registro que traigo con el cálculo en el query antes mencionado. Igual, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Esto se resuelve muy facil a partir de MySql 8.0 con `windows function`, pero entiendo por tu query que están trabajando con alguna versión anterior.

Una solución que se me ocurre es utilizar una variable `@aniomes` que contiene la concatenación del año y el mes. Ordenando por `id DESC` utilizas una sentencia `CASE`, si el valor de la variable `@aniomes` != `CONCAT(anio, mes)`, seteamos la variable con el año y el mes, y aparecerá en el resultado como la columna `ultimo`; sino, si coinciden ambos entonces la columna quedará con valor null.

Conclusión: el último registro de cada grupo (año y mes) contendrá el año y el mes concatenado en la columna `ultimo`, las demás filas contendrán null.

Luego filtras solo las filas en las cuales la columna `ultimo` no es nula.

Hice la query sobre el resultado de tu query (la tabla que sale en la pregunta, yo le llamé `t`), tu la tendrás que adapatar, ya que no cuento con la estructura y datos de prueba de las tablas reales.

```
SET @aniomes:=0;

SELECT id, anio, mes, acumulado
FROM (SELECT *,
             CASE WHEN @aniomes != CONCAT(anio, mes) THEN @aniomes:=concat(anio,mes) END AS ultimo
      FROM t
      ORDER BY anio, mes, id DESC) AS sq
WHERE ultimo IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY anio, mes;
```

Comment: Te dejo el [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cfa2a501e23e76aaaa846e00cdb06a06) para que lo puedas probar.